# instagram API platform policy

Tags: internet, intellectual-property, software

I just came across this:

> You cannot use "insta", "gram" or "Instagram" in your company or
>   product name.

on the instagram API platform policy, 
https://www.instagram.com/developer/

I am wondering: how can they do that? how can they forbid one from using such general terms (i am referring to gram and insta) in a product or company? 
It is logic to think that they would reject an application that is called in this way and uses their API but the statement seems to be more generic..

update: I don't have an instagram app or else in the works, i just want to understand how it works

update2: there is no sign of that statement in the [full platform policy](https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/)

Comment: "statement seems to be more generic": do you mean that you suspect they're trying to stop all companies from using those words in their names and those of their products?  The statement is one of several bullet points describing the platform policy.  Why would that statement apply outside the context of the policy (for example, for those who are not using the platform)?  I don't see how one could read this in a way that would attempt to restrict, for example, a cleaning company called Instaclean.

Comment: With regard to your update, the "full platform policy" incorporates by reference (in section B) the branding guidelines, which is a link to https://en.instagram-brand.com/.  There you will find a link to a page (https://en.instagram-brand.com/guidelines/general) that includes the rules about using "insta" and "gram," under the heading "Keep the word Instagram consistent."

Answer (score 3):

Fairly easily. You want to use their API. They give you the conditions for using it. As long as their conditions aren't illegal or unreasonable, you need to adhere to them to use their API.

Is it illegal to *not* include "insta", "gram", or "instagram" in your company or product name? Almost certainly not.

Is it an unreasonable term? Almost certainly not.

If you want to include "insta", "gram", or "instagram" in your company or product name, you can try - but you can't then use their API.

Comment: so you are saying this is only about the API... uhm i could not find a direct reference in the policy document, i will search again

Comment: @eddyce the first sentence in the platform policy is "By using the Instagram APIs, you agree to this policy."  Anyone not using the APIs is unaffected by the platform policy.

Comment: @phoog I added an update, didnt have the time to check before, there is no sign of that statement in the full platform policy, so why writing something that is not even in the legal doc?

Comment: @eddyce what do you mean by "full platform policy"?  I coped that from https://www.instagram.com/about/legal/terms/api/, which is a link on the page you linked to.  As I said, it's literally the first sentence on the page, immediately below the heading "Platform Policy."  So what do you mean when you say it's "something that is not even in the legal doc"?

Comment: @phoog from the main page: Before you start using the API Platform, we have a few guidelines that we'd like to tell you about. Please make sure to read the full Platform Policy. Here's what you'll read about:

Comment: @eddyce yes.  Then you click the link for the full platform policy (the one you added in your "update 2"), and the first sentence on that page is the one that I quoted in my [comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/21204/instagram-api-platform-policy/21209?noredirect=1#comment35185_21209).

Comment: so apparently it is only about using the api, i am accepting this answer